# Titan: Remove all connected Vertices

Tags: titan

I have following graph

```
   Vertex v1 = g.addVertex(null);
   Vertex v2 = g.addVertex(null);
   Vertex v3 = g.addVertex(null);
   v1.addEdge("v1v2", v2);
   v2.addEdge("v2v3", v3);
```

If I remove `v2` vertex, `v1v2` `v2v3` edge is deleted but `v1` `v3` vertex remain in graph. Will I have to remove `v1` and `v3` manually?

If I add another vertex:

```
Vertex v4 = g.addVertex(null);
v3.addEdge("v3v4", v4);

Vertex v5 = g.addVertex(null);
v5.addEdge("v5v3", v3);
```

Now If I will delete `v1` all vertices should be deleted. How to do that? Does titan provide something for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Titan doesn't provide anything that can detect orphaned vertices.  You will have to write your own approach to doing so.  I suppose you have at least two ways to deal with them.

1. If there's no harm in just leaving them there based on your
   schema/application, then let them remain orphaned.  Then batch
   remove them with Faunus or some other script.
2. Make removal of a `v2` in your first example, part of a transaction
   that does some quick edge checks on `v1` and `v3`.  If neither of
   those have edges then remove those vertices as well.

Comment: so In case of a tweet. If thousand reply is there for a tweet, and if i will delete tweet I will have to delete all thousand reply vertex manually.